# sharp symbol on sharp line

Tags: theory, accidentals

I'm trying to learn how the music staff works.  I want to know what note is actually played for a sharpened note on a sharped line, like this image here:

[image]

Am I suppose to play a note that sounds like the G note? Or is it still an F sharp note?

Comment: It's a courtesy accidental. No they don't add up, so you play F#, see: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24355/

Comment: If it's written like that in actual music, it's pretty pointless. The # sign (key sig.) couldn't be closer or clearer to the affected note anyway. And since it's a courtesy/cautionary sign, it should have brackets around it.

Answer (score 2):

It's still an F sharp note. This is usually what we call a "courtesy accidental". It's used to say that the note F would be sharp, when in a previous bar it was altered.

You can take a look on the wiki page for [courtesy accidentals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)#Courtesy_accidentals), where there is a list with when you would need to add such an accidental.

> - When the first note of a measure had an accidental in the previous measure
> - After a tie carries an accidental across a barline, and the same note appears in the next measure
> - When a chord contains a diminished or augmented octave
> - When there is a cross relation with another part

Answer (score 2):

> Am I suppose to play a note that sounds like the G note? Or is it still an F sharp note?

It is still an F sharp. For F double sharp the sharp next to the note would be replaced by an "x".

The reason the sharp sign appears for a second time is that previously F was changed to either natural or double sharp, etc., by an accidental next to the note, probably but not necessarily in the preceding bar. The second appearance of the sharp sign is a courtesy reminder to the musician that now we are in a new bar the original key signature applies.