# What is this note?

Tags: notation, key, key-signatures, accidentals

This is in key of F# major or D# minor, there is a D# in this key, but the D# in this picture has a double sharp sign beside it, so is it a D#(##) (which is an F)?[image]

Comment: (Ah, sorry; I didn't know this was already a question, or I wouldn't have answered.)

Comment: Probably a dup of https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/what-does-a-small-x-like-symbol-before-a-note-mean

Answer (score 25):

This is just D doublesharp, which is enharmonic to E.

The trick is that *key signatures are not additive*. In other words, any accidental added to a pitch is considered to be its own construct, not something *in addition to* what's already given in the key signature.

As such, this is not D♯ that is then sharped twice again, but rather just D doublesharp.

Comment: Yup. The cool thing about this is that any note on its own with an accidental modifying it is completely unambiguous, regardless of key signature. F with a sharp in front of it is always F♯, even if I'm in a key like C♭ major where F♭ is 'the diatonic F'. That's also why some complicated music for orchestras will have no key signatures at all and give all notes (with a couple obvious exceptions) an accidental to facilitate sight-reading.

Comment: Worth mentioning that although it's enharmonic to E nat., and E is # in the key sig., it stays as Dx. Also, it could have been written on the E space, *with* a nat. sign. This does look like someone's homework.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Richard's answer that if you wanted to "undo" the double-sharp (maybe you need a D sharp later within the same bar) you would have to put both a natural sign *and* a sharp sign *in sequence* before the note head. For example, take a look at bar 46 from the *Prelude* in C-sharp Minor, BWV 873 from the *Well-Tempered Clavier*, Vol. II, by Johann Sebastian Bach (BGA XIV, ed. 1866):
[image]
The key signature requires an F sharp (here it's marked on the lower F in the treble, this being an old-fashioned edition), an F double-sharp is needed in the top voice, and then the alteration is canceled on the next F by means of a natural-sharp combination. You can think of the "X" symbol on the first F standing for two sharps, and the natural sign on the second F canceling only the first sharp, while the second sharp is reiterated for good measure.

The same should be done for double-flats.