# Anyone know the meaning of a cross on piano sheet music?

Tags: piano

I would be grateful if anyone can tell me what  a cross in front of each of a pair of notes on the bass clef mean? Does it mean you don't actually play that note (the same pair precede the pair with the cross in front of it.

Maybe the preceding pair are meant to linger longer) (linger longer, that sounds funny!) but then wouldn't they show it as needing a pedal? Not that I know where I'd find that thingy.

Please don't shoot me down as it's obvious I haven't a clue what I'm doing but actually I'm doing it quite well believe it or not despite knowing nothing! In case you're interested I had a piano 20 years ago and got the sheet music for Moonlight Sonata (aiming high from the start!). I can't read music and still can't but I wrote all the letters underneath all the notes (which took about 3 weeks!!!!) on 1st movement of Moonlight Sonata.

I can't play chopsticks but I started big. I learnt the whole thing by rote, by heart one note at a time. It took me one year to perfect. It sounded ridiculously professional. Then I sold the piano. 20 years later, I'm starting over as I couldn't remember any of it.

A week in and I've got the first page down. Three more to go! This is what old people do. It was either that or Wordle but I manage both. When I knew it by heart first time around, I played along with Alfred Brendell one day. (He wasn't in the room with me, just an album obvs!). I promise you, I kept up amazingly well. I don't suppose I use the right fingers but as it's the the only piece I'm ever likely to play, given,sadly, that I won't get to Rach 2 or even Dave Brubeck's Blue Rondo A La Turk or A La anything else, so I don't think it will matter too much.

I should be a tick tock sensation getting no end of free wrinkle cream sent in my direction but I don't know what tick tock is. I digress. If anyone knows if my hunch about the cross is correct, I would be so pleased to hear. Thank you. And if you know of any other little traps I should be aware of in this piece of music, I'd love to know. Thank you.

Comment: A pic would help - is it + or x?

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of that. the second one. Thanks.

Comment: This is called a double sharp and raises a note twice. It is identical to `##`.

Comment: Gooodness! I never knew that! Thank you. Be interested to see how it sounds now. Appreciate your help and Tim too.

Comment: What research have you done? If I google cross and sheet music I get this here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/what-does-a-small-x-like-symbol-before-a-note-mean

Comment: Also it is not the same question if it is not a prefix. If it is staved it might mean something else.