# Why is it the C Major scale that is played without accidentals, instead of A

Tags: theory, scales, key

Why is it C's Major scale that comes without accidentals instead of A?

The C Major scale is played C D E F G A B C

The C chromatic scale is played C C# D D# E F F# G G# A A# B C

Why was it decided that instead of (Shifting the letters of C chromatic down two) A A# B B# C D D# E E# F F# G A

Basically if you wrote on the white piano keys, the A would be written on the C key.

My question is more about why it's called C instead of A, rather than having anything to do with the pitches. As a related side question, what importance does A have besides being a tuning reference.

Comment: Have a look at these posts: [Why is music theory built so tightly around the C Major scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/why-is-music-theory-built-so-tightly-around-the-c-major-scale),
[Why is C the base note of standard notation and keys?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/893/why-is-c-the-base-note-of-standard-notation-and-keys),
[Why is the key of C the one key with no sharps or flats?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43315/why-is-the-key-of-c-the-one-key-with-no-sharps-or-flats)

Comment: @ElementsInSpace oops, thank you

Comment: It's actually a hugely interesting question on a few different levels.  Welcome to the site; I hope you'll stick around.