# What are whole steps and half steps?

Tags: theory

My choir teacher talks to my class about whole steps, and half steps a lot. The problem is, I am unable to understand what whole step and half steps are. What are whole steps and half steps?

Comment: These are intervals that measure the distance between two pitches. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65309/how-do-you-identify-whole-step-and-half-step-between-notes-on-sheet-music may address your question.

Comment: I think this question should have some in-depth answers. Not sure whether steps are the same as tones...You should really be asking choir teacher to explain, even they might not fully understand the terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Step" is the generic term for moving from one musical letter to the next.  But not all steps are the same size - if you look at a piano you'll see there is no black key between E and F or between B and C.

So we call those smaller steps *half steps*, and the larger ones (A-B, C-D, D-E, F-G, G-A) are *whole steps*

Comment: So what does that make C>Db? Or even C#>Db, as the musical letter name has changed. Tone/semitone is so much simpler!

Comment: The US terms are "diatonic half step" for C-Db and "chromatic half step" for C-C#.  C#-Db isn't described as a step of any kind on either side of the pond, because they're enharmonic, and the term "step" (or "tone") is too generic.  C#-Db is a doubly-diminished second when it needs a name.

Answer (score 2):

In standard 'Western' musical thinking, the octave is divided into 12 semitones, or 'half-steps'. A half-step is simply the distance between one note in the 12-tone (or 'chromatic') scale, and the next note down or up.

A half-step is the same thing as a semitone - so C to C# is a half-step; C to Db is a half-step; B to C is also a half-step. If you play any key on the piano keyboard, and then play the next note up or down (whether that happens to be black or white), you've moved up by a half-step.

A step is just two half-steps. So C to D is a step.

In most music, we don't use all 12 notes of the scale, but just a subset, such as the Major scale. Scales can be defined in terms of steps - for example, the step sizes in the major scale are:
 *whole, whole, half, whole, whole, whole, half*.
 If we check this against the C major scale, we see that there is:

A *whole* step between C and D
A *whole* step between D and E
A *half* step between E and F
A *whole* step between F and G
A *whole* step between G and A
A *whole* step between A and B
A *half* step between B and C

Comment: This may - or may *not* - be the same answer as Tom's. I'm not quite sure! :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to get complicated here.   Adjacent note in the chromatic scale - 'Half-step' (American) or 'Semitone' (British).  Next-note-but-one - 'Whole-step' (American) or 'Tone' (British).   And if 'chromatic scale' hangs you up, it's all the notes on the piano keyboard, white and black. All the fret positions on a guitar. Not just the selection of them that form a major or minor scale.

Unlike interval names (Major 2nd, Minor 2nd) Half-steps and Whole-steps have nothing to do with note spelling.  It's just pure counting.

Sit down at a keyboard with a more advanced musician and get him to demonstrate the chromatic scale, other scales and what a close-spaced 'Half-step' and a slightly more distant 'Whole-step' sounds like.  That will be more use than pages of description!

And, yes, both 'step' and 'tone' have other musical meanings.  Cope with it!