# Why the F clef and G clef?

Tags: history, clefs

We understand that the bass clef is called the F clef, while the treble is called the G clef. It's to do with *where* the strange signs are on each staff. But why those notes in particular?

Comment: The answers to Berodrito Pembrunk's question raised more questions…

Comment: I don't know, but I would note that there are also the C clefs (alto clef being the most commonly seen of these for viola parts). There's an interval of a fifth between F and C and from C to G which probably plays some role.

Comment: The shapes of the strange signs are meant to represent the letters.

Comment: Are they called F and G clefs even among advanced musicians? I thought it was just to ease music theory on beginners. I'm not used to using these names like I used Treble, Alto and Bass

Comment: @RishiNandha_M - that's o.k., except alto is the movable C clef.

Comment: I already gave a detailed answer to this question [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/why-are-clefs-associated-with-reference-notes-g-f-and-c/91793#91793).

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know the history enough to be certain, but I imagine it comes out of the Medieval hexachord system where the three hexachord types were based on `F`, `C`, and `G`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guidonian_hand#The_hexachord_in_the_Middle_Ages

Comment: and the external link: http://www.medieval.org/emfaq/harmony/hex1.html

Answer (score 4):

Like Michael says the C- and F-clef come from the Guidonian hand ans show where the semitone lies: below C or F

When F was altered to the  lead tone F# the semitone was lying below G.

If we look at the 5 lines of the staff we couldn't see the semitones (without the clefs) as all lines have the same distance.

Riemann writes in his 
CATECHISM
OF
MUSICAL HISTORY

> To these two oldest clefs, the g-clef, which showed once marked g, was
>   already added in the 13th century; but for the music of that time,
>   which was written exclusively for the voice, it was extremely seldom
>   required. It was only in theoretical synopses, or at most in the
>   sketching of scores, that V was written for our great G. As the clef
>   originally showed the place where the semitonium lay, the g-clef at
>   once indicated that f was raised to f$; therefore, where this
>   transposition of keys into the dominant (which seldom happened), was
>   not intended, and the g-clef was only chosen to avoid ledger lines, we
>   often find a flat on the f line, as a sign that the lower form of f (fb molle, i. e. not f$, but f) is meant.