# What is the origin and original meaning of "tonic", "supertonic", "mediant", etc.?

Tags: scales, terminology, history, modes

Each of the pitches in the diatonic scale has a "name":

```
tonic
supertonic
mediant
subdominant
dominant
submediant
subtonic
```

I was first introduced to `tonic`, `dominant`, and `subdominant` in the context of "`dominant` chords lead to `tonic` chords, and `subdominant` chords lead to `dominant` chords". My own logical inference suggested that the "sub" in "subdominant" meant "less important" given its role in relation to the `dominant`.

Later, I learned that `mediant` and `submediant` are a third above and below the `tonic`, respectively, and, similarly, the `supertonic` and `subtonic` are a second above and below the `tonic`.

That leaves me with some confusion about `dominant` and `subdominant`. `Subdominant` could mean "one step below the `dominant`", but that would be inconsistent, since the others are relative to the `tonic`. Or it could mean that `dominant` and `subdominant` are a fifth above and below the `tonic`, but this is also inconsistent: why would scale degrees `2`, `3`, and `5` be named relative to the tonic rather than `2`, `3`, and `4`?

My vague understanding is that these terms predate the diatonic scale, finding their origins in earlier (chant/modal) theories, and perhaps even as terms borrowed or adapted from ancient Greek theory.

**Where do these terms come from, what were their original meanings, and what was their musical significance?**

---

This question has its origin in the discussion in the comments of this post: [Answer: What are the degrees of a pentatonic scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109905/what-are-the-degrees-of-a-pentatonic-scale/109908#109908)

---

**UPDATE**

Wikipedia's ["Submediant" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submediant#:%7E:text=The%20term%20mediant%20appeared%20in,Untermediante%20is%20found%20in%201771.) contains this interesting tidbit:

> In French and Italian, a conception with two centres, subtonic (sous-tonique, sotto-tonica) and supertonic (sustonique, sopra-tonica) on both sides of the tonic, subdominant (sous-dominante, sotto-dominante) and "superdominant" (sus-dominante, sopra-dominante) on both sides of the dominant – and the mediant left alone between the two.

The English/German terminology was used in constructing the present question, in which the super/sub designations relate to position relative to the tonic. But the French/Italian terminology supports the intuition that "subdominant" should mean "below the dominant" (see first paragraph above).

```
subtonic
tonic
supertonic

mediant

subdominant
dominant
superdominant
```

Comment: "why would scale degrees 2, 3, and 5 be named relative to the tonic rather than 2, 3, and 4?" I would argue that they're *all* named in relation to tonic, it's just that some are measured in different directions.

Comment: It would appear that 'subtonic' is not part of the diatonic scale, being (news to me) the *flattened* seventh note. The seventh note in the diatonic scale is the leading note/tone.

Comment: What befuddles me is this: If 'sub' means under. Subdominant is under the dominant. Sub tonic is under the tonic. So why isn't submediant under the mediant? I know the mediant is halfway between dominant and tonic, and submediant is halfway between tonic and subdominant (the other way!), but that's hardly logic - is it?

Comment: @Tim: It's explained in the question and in Richard's answer: mediant is a third above the tonic; submediant is a third below the tonic. Likewise, dominant is a fifth above the tonic; subdominant is a fifth below the tonic.

Comment: I do understand it ! It's just a bit spurious to my logical way of thinking. And with sub referring to under, who would not be forgiven as a beginner, to question the sub/mediant positioning?

Comment: @Tim The update regarding "superdominant" versus "submediant" might interest you.

Comment: Now that's intuitive! And unequivocal ! Makes a lot more sense, logically, particularly to those meeting the terms initially. Eschew English/German and favour Italian/French. After all, the majority of terms musical are founded in the latter...

Comment: Someday I might get around to writing a full answer to this question, but I just wanted to note regarding the apparent controversy around whether the "sub" in subdominant is a tone under the dominant or a fifth under the tonic, note that this was a debate going back to the origin of the terms in the 18th century. Rousseau in his Dictionary wonders a bit about how submediant might therefore refer to either scale degree 6 or 2; as I recall, he concludes that seeing submediant as 6 (mediant under tonic) is better for "composition," and thus "subdominant" can be interpreted similarly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a little complex to answer, because "dominant" has been used to mean different things over time. In the (late) Middle Ages, "dominant" actually just meant "reciting tone," which would be a fifth above the final of authentic modes and a fourth above the final for plagal modes.

The first appearance of "mediant" that I'm aware of was in a treatise in 1639 by Antoine Parran, where he both fixes the *note dominante* to be the fifth above the final and introduces the *mediante*, the point between the final and the *note dominante*.

As far as I can tell, it was Jean-Philippe Rameau (1683–1764) who introduced "subdominant." Quoting Joel Lester in his chapter ("Rameau and eighteenth-century harmonic theory") in the *Cambridge History of Western Music Theory* (p. 768):

> In practical matters, there were several important additions to Rameau's theory after the *Traité* [*de l'harmonie* of 1722]. Among the most important are the introduction of the *subdominant* (*sous-dominante*)...in the *Nouveau système* (1726)...which became central to his theory of tonality in the *Génération harmonique* (1737), even though [it is] already implicitly present in his *Traité*. Beginning with the *Génération harmonique*, he posits the tonal organization of a key as the tonic surrounded by an upper and lower fifth—a dominant and subdominant.

Thus the subdominant is clearly understood as a fifth *below* tonic, not the scale degree immediately below dominant. (And note, by the way, that before Rameau, the "dominant" was actually called the *dominante-tonique*!)

As for the remaining terms—supertonic, etc.—I admit I'm not certain. My guess is somewhere between Rameau and Riemann, but I'm currently not able to verify this. But I think what's important is that these terms were added (and, in some cases, their definitions were changed to match their current usage) over time and by various different authors.

Comment: So, my assumption about the subdominant and the "role" of submediant was actually more correct than I thought. Is there any historyc reference about the relation between the major/lydian and minor scales built on tonic and subdominant?