# Are the names of scale degrees the same for different modes?

Tags: scales, modes, intervals

Do the naming conventions and their implied function still apply to modes outside the major and minor scale?
Is the *minor second* of the Phrygian mode called the *supertonic?*
Is the *augmented fourth* of the Lydian mode called the *subdominant?*
Is the *diminished fifth* of the Locrian mode called the *dominant?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes: in my experience, these scale-degree names can still be used to indicate members of various modes. In practice, however, I would say that references to the dominant and tonic of any of these modes are far more common than references to other scale degrees.

I can only think of two caveats with my answer:

1. Like in major and minor, the use of "leading tone" and "subtonic" will depend on whether scale-degree 7 is a half step or a whole step below tonic.
2. And in scales of more or less than 7 notes (that is, scales that are not heptatonic), we have to be really careful with what we mean. In a C-major pentatonic collection, for example, people use the term "dominant" not to mean the fifth scale degree (which is in one sense actually an A here), but rather the interval of a fifth above tonic (and thus G).

For a closely related question (and one with some different viewpoints), see [What are the degrees of a pentatonic scale called?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/109905/21766)