# Please list every type of interval, (Perfect, Major, minor, Augmented and diminished), from Most Consonant to Most Dissonant

Tags: theory, consonance-and-dissonance

Please list every type of interval, (Perfect, Major, minor, Augmented and diminished), from Most Consonant to Most Dissonant. I cannot find this information anywhere online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since there are too many variables to give a definite answer. What tuning are you in?

Comment: There are a few problems to resolve with this question: 1) it's inherently objective; 2) the perception of consonance and dissonance of intervals has changed over time; 3) what is the tuning system? 4) What about doubly augmented or diminished intervals? 5) The consonance or dissonance can depend on musical context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the list of intervals in order of dissonance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46509/what-is-the-list-of-intervals-in-order-of-dissonance)

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion mostly. Context matters. Hindemith does make such a list but it's not the same as others do.

The usual classification is somewhat like this:

Perfect intervals: unison. octave, fifth, fourth*

Imperfect consonances: major and minor thirds and sixths.

Dissonances: all seconds, sevenths, augmented and diminished intervals, *the fourth against the bass

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So, that basically implies the order is typically Perfect, Major, minor, Augmented and diminished??? (Which is exactly how I wrote it in this title lol), but I actually thought the order was: (Perfect, Augmented, Major, minor and diminished), but I suppose the correct order is the former, and not the latter, of these 2 orders.

Comment: @DaveLittle Most people think a minor third is more consonant than a major second, so you can’t just go by order of qualities. You have to consider the number also.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Well, in that response, Todd, I am now going to ask a different, but similar, question, which is, “Can a Major 3rd also be called a Perfect 5th, and can a Perfect 5th also be called a Major 3rd? Why or why not? Please be thorough in your explanation.”.

Comment: @DaveLittle Sounds like a homework question which we normally don’t deal with here. But no, a major third and perfect fifth are completely different intervals. That’s like asking if 7 could be called 4 or 4 called 7.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Oh, sorry, Todd. That was my bad. I meant to ask, “Can a Major 3rd also be called a Perfect 3rd, and can a Perfect 5th also be called a Major 5th? Why or why not? Please be thorough in your explanation.”. *

Comment: @DaveLittle Nope. I mean you can call a thing whatever you want to call it but if no one else calls it that then what’s the point?