Is there a dissonance measure that allows comparison between chords of different size?
It came to my attention that intervals often sound less dissonant if they occur in the context of a chord rather than being played isolated, e.g. C-B on its own sounds more dissonant to my ear than the Cmaj7 chord C-E-G-B which includes C-B.
I'm wondering if there is a general dissonance measure that allows comparing C-B and C-E-G-B by mapping it to a single value (let's say between 0 and 1).
I know about roughness calculation, however in the texts it is suggested that chord roughness should be determined by adding the roughness value R(f1, f2) of each frequency pair (f1, f2), meaning that for the chord C-E-G-B total roughness is calculated by
R(C, E) + R(C, G) + R(C, B) + R(E, G) + R(E, B) + R(G, B)
This is always bigger than the roughness of the single interval R(C, B), since R(C, B) is part of the sum, so chords are always measured as "more dissonant" than the single intervals they consist of.
More generally: If the roughness of a frequency set R(f1, f2, ..., fn) is recursively defined as the addition of all pair values R(f, f') then note sets of different size cannot be compared effectively: A triad will always be rougher than the intervals in it. A tetrad will always be rougher than the triads that can be constructed by removing a note from it, etc.
This goes against the intuition of the first observation, that C-E-G-B sounds less dissonant than C-B alone.
EDIT: edited for clarity that it is about comparing frequency sets of different size

This question has come up before, ex. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-consonance-or-dissonance-of-a-chord

This question is similar to: Is there a way to measure the consonance or dissonance of a chord?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The measures discussed in the answers of that questions are defined on intervals / pairs of frequencies. Also in the answers of the question it is suggested that the measures should be added for each interval pair in a chord, which makes it impossible to compare chords of different size. i will edit for clarity.
